# Sunrise and Sunset is not Smooth with CSS3 animation and linear-gradient

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, linear-gradients

I am developing a Sunrise and Sunset animation with CSS3, Please check runtime [jsFiddle output](http://jsfiddle.net/_Sud/4VgCy/embedded/result/).

Sun is transiting from one color to another color as expected

#### Noon

[Click For Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9EKd.png)

[image]

#### After Noon

[Click For Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPiWo.png)

[image]

#### Evening

[Click For Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufum0.png)

[image]

#### Night

[Click For Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztafv.png)

[image]

#### Early Morning

[Click For Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKdjq.png)

[image]

Problem lies in ***Sky transition from one mode to another mode***, the color changes are abrupt and are not linear

#### Code Used for Sky Color Change

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeSkyColor /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    1%{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 152, 209, 1) 0%,rgb(202, 229, 243) 40%,rgba(125, 185, 232, 0.82) 100%); /* Background of Sky */
    }
    11%{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 152, 209, 1) 0%,rgb(202, 229, 243) 40%,rgba(125, 185, 232, 0.82) 100%); /* Background of Sky */
    }
    33%  {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240, 231, 26) 0%,rgb(245, 86, 12) 50%,rgba(197, 127, 81, 0.82) 100%); /* Background of Sky */
    }
    66%  {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(34, 33, 3) 0%,rgb(162, 55, 5) 50%,rgb(24, 10, 1) 100%); /* Background of Sky */
    }
    100% {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(5, 5, 5, 1) 0%,rgb(54, 55, 56) 40%,rgb(3, 3, 3) 100%); /* Background of Sky */
    }
}
```

Please Check [JsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/_Sud/4VgCy/)**(It is with comments)**.

- Are we not supposed to use linear-gradient in Animations?
- If so, How to make Sky Color transit Smoothly?

Is there some thing i am missing? I Would be thankful if some one can give me some references or any pointers to take it forward.

Comment: At least accordingly to w3, it shouldn't be posible:    [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/]. May be the only alternative would to have both gradients at the same time (in a pseudo element) and animating opacity ?

Comment: @vals:This sounds as a good option :) .. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is apply the entire gradient, start to finish, onto a single element (for my example, I'll use `#sky`) and then animate the position of that element to make it look like the colors are fading. Twitter's Bootstrap uses this trick for animating the background on the button hovers.

See my fork of your JSFiddle with this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/jakebellacera/6Zabx/

Here's the CSS I added:

```
#sky {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900%; /* This must be in a factor of three */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,152,209,1) 0%, rgb(202, 229, 243) 11%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0.82) 22%,
                                                   rgb(240, 231, 26) 33%, rgb(245, 86, 12) 44%,   rgba(197, 127, 81, 0.82) 55%,
                                                   rgba(5, 5, 5, 1) 66%,  rgb(54, 55, 56) 77%,    rgb(3, 3, 3) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,152,209,1) 0%, rgb(202, 229, 243) 11%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0.82) 22%,
                                                rgb(240, 231, 26) 33%, rgb(245, 86, 12) 44%,   rgba(197, 127, 81, 0.82) 55%,
                                                rgba(5, 5, 5, 1) 66%,  rgb(54, 55, 56) 77%,    rgb(3, 3, 3) 100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: changeSkyColor; /* Change Shiny Sky to evening sky and to darkness */  /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 14s; /* Total time of animation */
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Just another timing function */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Lets repeat sunrise and sunset till world ends :) */
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* Lets do in alternate fashion */
    -moz-animation-name: changeSkyColor; /* Change Shiny Sky to evening sky and to darkness */  /* Mozzilla */
    -moz-animation-duration: 14s; /* Total time of animation */
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Just another timing function */
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Lets repeat sunrise and sunset till world ends :) */
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate; /* Lets do in alternate fashion */
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeSkyColor /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    0%{
        top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        top: -800%; /* #sky's height - 100% */
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes changeSkyColor /* Mozilla */
{

    0%{
        top: 0px;
    }
    100%  {
        top: -800%; /* #sky's height - 100% */
    }
}
```

Comment: Great approach, can you also let me know why  `height: 900%; /* This must be in a factor of three */` have you used code for factor of 3

Comment: So it is evenly divisible by the three "type" of sky (sunrise, sunset, night)